# Vuetify: How to align icon and long text on the same row?

Tags: vuetify.js

In my vue.js 2.5.7 / vuetify": "^1.0.8" application I use a card with a title containing some text and an icon to the left of text:

```
    <v-card class="p-3" tile="true">

        <v-card-title class="headline">
            <v-icon color="teal" class="a_link" v-if="confirm_modal_dialog_icon" left="true">{{ confirm_modal_dialog_icon }}</v-icon>
            {{ confirm_modal_dialog_confirm_text }}
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text v-if="confirm_modal_dialog_detailed_text">
            {{ confirm_modal_dialog_detailed_text }}
        </v-card-text>
```

If `confirm_modal_dialog_confirm_text` variable contains a long text then the title spans over two lines:

1. icon
2. text

Can I make icon (on the left) and long text to always display on the same row? If yes how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem as you describe it happens because the text does not fit inside the `v-card-title` tag. One way to solve this is to add the below css.

Use `white-space: nowrap;`. Or you could add a class to `v-card-title` like this little snippet of code:

```
.one-line {
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/maxkoi/pen/ZMoWZo) illustrates how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.text-truncate` [provided by Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/typography#text-wrapping).

```
<v-card-title class="headline text-truncate">
  <v-icon color="teal" class="a_link" v-if="confirm_modal_dialog_icon">
    {{ confirm_modal_dialog_icon }}
  </v-icon>
  {{ confirm_modal_dialog_confirm_text }}
</v-card-title>
```

Also I think you can drop the `left="true"` on the `v-icon`. [The documentation states that this is for buttons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons#api).